How can I add a timezone to the datetime filter of a MUI datagrid?
I have a MUI Datagrid that has datetime columns. The user can select a period of time for which they want to see data, including in what timezone they would like to see the dates formatted.
Now when the user uses the built-in filter function of MUI Datagrid, the time selected always uses the users Locale.
This will give confusing results. For example:

User selects filter: 'startedAt' - 'isAfter' - 15/07/2024 00:00:00'
User has Locale timezone UTC+2
User wants to display the time in UTC so has this selected in the period picker.
Table shows an item with 'startedAt' at 14/07/2024 22:05:00

This is not ideal since the user will think the filter isnt working
I have tried passing the timezone to the valueGetter like so:
valueGetter: ({ value }) => value && dayjs(value).tz(timezone).toDate()
But this doesn't work, either because the timezone is just a representation of a point in time and MUI compares to an actual Date object, which doesn't care about timezone. Or because the Date object always gets outputted in the users Locale timezone and uses that representation to compare against.
Ideally what I want is to tell MUI to use a specific timezone when selecting the filter.
Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to completely write my own custom filter?
